# How can I select URLs of a particular type with XPath & Scrapy

Tags: python, xml, regex, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to select only links of the type `http://lyricsindia.net/songs/show/*` from an HTML which contains links likes this:

```
<a href="http://lyricsindia.net/songs/show/550" class=l>LyricsIndia.net dhiimii </a>
<a href="http://smriti.com/hindi-songs/dhiimii-dhiimii-bhiinii-bhiinii-utf8" class=l>dhiimii Songs Archive</a>
```

I have gone through the Scrapy documentation, but haven't been able to figure this out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this XPath:

```
//a[starts-with(@href, 'http://lyricsindia.net/songs/show/')]
```